# Rows Property of UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and trying to understand how to use a `UniformGrid`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid

> If no value for `Rows` and `Columns` are provided, the UniformGrid will create a square layout based on the total number of visible items.
> If a fixed size is provided for `Rows` and `Columns` then additional children that can't fit in the number of cells provided won't be displayed.

Based on this text, I thought if I bind a collection of 10 items to a uniform grid and specify 1 row and 3 columns then it would only show 3 items and the other 7 would be cut off.

However, I have built a sample application and with 1 row, 3 columns, and 10 items in my collection, I am getting 4 rows displayed.  Here is my sample application:

```
<Window x:Class="UniformGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UniformGridTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Name="MyMainWindow">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveList}" Background="Black">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding ItemDescription}" Background="Black" Foreground="White"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace UniformGridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly PlatformSelectorViewModel platformSelectorViewModel = new PlatformSelectorViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = platformSelectorViewModel;
        }
    }

    public class PlatformSelectorViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SelectorItem> ActiveList { get; }

        public PlatformSelectorViewModel()
        {
            ActiveList = new ObservableCollection<SelectorItem>();
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Super Nintendo Entertainment System" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Nintendo Entertainment System" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Sega Genesis" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Sega CD" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Turbo Grafx 16" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Nintendo Gamecube" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Nintendo Wii" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Sony Playstation" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Nintendo PSP" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Nintendo Playstation 2" });
            ActiveList.Add(new SelectorItem() { ItemDescription = "Arcade" });
        }
    }

    public class SelectorItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string itemDescription;
        public string ItemDescription
        {
            get { return itemDescription; }
            set
            {
                itemDescription = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ItemDescription"));
            }
        }

        private bool isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                isSelected = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: A uniform grid with 3 rows and 4 columns displaying 11 items (the last cell is empty).]

Based on the documentation on `UniformGrid`, I had expected that I would get 1 row with 3 items uniformly laid out and the other 7 items would not display. Did I misunderstand the documentation or am I doing something incorrectly that is causing additional rows to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are refering to the wrong documentation, yours is for **UWP**, not WPF.

- [UWP `UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid)
- [WPF `UniformGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

The behavior should be the same, but it is not explicitly stated in the referenced documentation for WPF. However, there seems to be an issue that stems from setting `VerticalAlignment` to `Center` and is not related to the `ItemsControl`, it will be the same for an isolated `UniformGrid`.

Whenever the `UniformGrid` contains more than the maximum number of items it can display (`Rows` x `Columns`) **and** the `VerticalAlignment` is set to any other value than the default `Stretch`, all of the items are displayed regardless of the number of rows, but respecting the number of columns.

What you could do is remove the `VerticalAlignment` and try to compensate for it by aligning the `ItemsControl` in a way that it fits your original intent.

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
   <UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Rows="1" Columns="3"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me the uniform grid still shows to many rows…anything else i could try? @thatguy